# How to update value in sessionStorage on method click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have pay() method. A wallet balance is shown with certain coins. When pay() is clicked data is updated in purchase data. Coins data is stored in sessionStorage, but, after refresh of page data is missing.

Payment method

```
const onPayment = async (coins, _id) => { 
  try {
    await fetch(`${config.baseUrl}customers/purchaseproduct?content_id=${_id}&coins=${coins}&v=1.0`, {
      method:'POST', 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'ApiKey': config.apiKey,
        'Authorization':sessionStorage.getItem('tokenNew'),   
        'platform':'web'
      },
    }).then((data) => data.json()).then((data2) => {
      const balanceUpdated = data2.data.purchase.coins_after_txn
      console.log('new balance', balanceUpdated) //new balance: 49990
           
      {/* Here coins data is updated only on click of pay() method  later on page refresh sessionStorage 
          value is empty */}
      sessionStorage.setItem('walletData', balanceUpdated)
    })
  }
  catch({error}) {
    toast.error(error)
  }

}
```

As you can see 'coins' are the price of product whereas '_id' is the id of specific product in onPayment method. walletData is updated only on payment and when refreshed the page, data is empty.

Take an example, A product price is $90 when clicked on pay() method $90 is cut from wallet 'balanceUpdated' and then passed on to sessionStorage in 'walletData' which is shown at that instance i.e 4900 but when page is refreshed 'walletData' is empty.

How to store the new updated value in sessionStorage and will remain it even after refresh?

LoginNow file

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => { 
    try {
       let newData = await fetch('customers/auth/login', {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'ApiKey': config.apiKey,
          'Platform': 'web',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)  
      });
      newData = await newData.json();

      if(newData.error == true) {
        toast.error(newData.error_messages[0])
      } else {
        const tokenData = newData.data.token
        const walletData = newData.data.coinsxp.coins
  
      sessionStorage.setItem('tokenNew', tokenData);
      sessionStorage.setItem('walletData', walletData); 
      }
    }
    catch({error}) {   
        toast.error(error)      
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can we see the code that retrieves the value from the session storage?

Comment: I have edited the code please see above

Comment: There is no code that retrieves the item from sessionstorage, should be something like
`data = sessionStorage.getItem('walletData')`

Comment: OK so what would be the correct approach? Can you please show it?. I mean the data that is retrieved from 'walletData' is then updated only on click of pay() and then its null on  refresh

Answer (score 0):

The data is probably there in the sessionStorage, you just have to retrieve it and write it in memory, on startup.

Probably you want something like this (or the other way around, depending on which value you want to have precedence):

```
    const walletData = newData.data.coinsxp.coins || sessionStorage.getItem('walletData');
```

Putting data in sessionstorage is not equivalent to making it persistent. Putting data in sessionStorage means that it will just stay in session storage, it doesn't mean that your app data will be updated automatically based on it. This is why every time you call `setItem`, you should also call `getItem` - otherwise you are just stashing stuff somewhere, without accessing it.

Comment: OK so you mean data I'am getting from 'walletData' in sessionStorage will then be stored in walletData value., but, how are we going to replace the wallet data recieved from onPayment() and then store it in sessionStorage i.e it will update accordingly

Comment: Not following exactly, but you have to update the `sessionStorage` every time you update the value, will update my answer

Comment: Ya right... my intention is that value from onPayment() should update the sessionStorage.setItem('walletData', balanceUpdated). This is where I'am stuck... Not getting updated and showing null on refresh

Comment: When persisting data in sessionStorage.setItem('walletData', balanceUpdated). The value 'balanceUpdated' shows null on browser refresh

Comment: Yeah, that's because you have to retrieve the value you previously saved in localStorage and assign it to the variable:   `const walletData = sessionStorage.getItem('walletData');`

Comment: OK but, will that update the new balanceUpdated in sessionStorage if yes then how?